# How to access the picturebox from a new class?

Tags: c#, oop, visual-studio-2013

Here is my "Card" class:

```
public class Card
{
    public Card()
    {

    }

    public void Generate()
    {                                   
        frmMain0 frmMain0 = new frmMain0();    
        Player Spieler = new Player();

        //some code here

        Graphics g = frmMain0.pbCard.CreateGraphics();
        SolidBrush bWhite = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        Font fntDebug = new Font("Arial", 8);
        g.DrawString("fsdfsdfcdsfcdscfdsfsdfsdfs", fntDebug, bWhite, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

And here is the main Form:

```
public partial class frmMain0 : Form
{
    public frmMain0()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMain0_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Card Karte = new Card();
        Karte.Generate();                   
    }
}
```

Visual Studio lets me debug the code but I don't see the text on my picture, what am I doing from here?

Comment: I created the picture box via (Forms) designer btw.

Comment: You're doing it wrong... You need to start drawing when the `OnPaint` event occurs for your `PictureBox`. Then, you'll easily get the Graphics object from the PaintEventArgs, BTW

Comment: Could you post how I do it in my case?

Comment: you can add the OnPaint event handler to your PictureBox automatically from the VS designer. Then, in it, do something like `e.Graphics.DrawString("fsdfsdfcdsfcdscfdsfsdfsdfs", fntDebug, bWhite, 10, 10);`

Comment: Picturebox has no OnPaint event, only a Paint event.

I already tried it with the paint Event, but it seems to have the same effect like the code above.

Comment: yeah, I meant `Paint`. Anyway, show your code with it...